# How to convert a native query to JPQL

Tags: jpa

I have this problem with JPA Query. [DER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdTJ2.png)

Customers make purchases and can purchase products with a limit of 1 unit per purchase per day.
This is my Native Query:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Producto p where p.idProducto not in (SELECT c.detalles FROM Compra c"
    + " JOIN c.detalles det" + " where (c.cliente=?1 and (DATE(c.fecha) = CURRENT_DATE()))"
    + " GROUP BY det.id_producto" + " HAVING (sum(det.cantidad<=1)))")
List<Producto> getProductosHabilitadosPorCliente(int idCliente);
```

ERROR: expecting CLOSE, found '<=' near line 1, column 278.

Thanks!!

Comment: `sum(det.cantidad<=1)` I think you're missing a `)` here after `det.cantidad`.

Comment: First of all, this looks to be native SQL, so you will need to add `native=true` inside the `@Query` annotation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:
`@Query("SELECT p FROM Producto p WHERE p.idProducto NOT IN (SELECT d.producto FROM Compra c JOIN c.detalles d WHERE ((c.cliente.idCliente=?1) AND (DATE(c.fecha)=CURRENT_DATE())) GROUP BY d.producto HAVING SUM(d.cantidad)>=3")")`